# Links from localhost dont work properly

Tags: wampserver

When i go to localhost (Wampserver index page) and click on one of the project the url goes to 'project-name/' instead of 'localhost/project-name'

Also, some projects open correctly when i directly go to 'localhost/project-name' and some don't (Internal Server Error). Where is the catch?

I have new pc (win 8.1) and I have just installed the newest version of Wampserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a solution,

1. Open Your Favorite Text Editor.
2. Open the file located at c:/wamp/www/index.php
3. Find line that says

   $suppress_localhost = true;
4. Change the line to:

   $suppress_localhost = false;
5. Save the file and refresh localhost and your project links will now work.

Dont forget to +1 me if it works! 
Cheers

Comment: The best solution is to create a Virtual Host for each of your projects. Then the new index.php will work properly as designed.